# Is there a simulation technology testing both VHDL code and ADC/DAC?

Tags: simulation

With HDL simulators like Modelsim, possible to check HDL codes (similar I2C/SPI).
Some of analog ICs(similar OPAMP) have SPICE models.
I'm not sure that SPICE models of SPI/I2C controlled ICs could be possible ?
Also is it possible to test them with HDL code in a same simulation software?
[image]

Comment: Why do want to incorporate the ADC into your functional simulation?  Are you wanting to test the FPGA interface (I2C/SPI)?

Comment: I may not be able to express well. Yes,for testing digital interface. I want to add VHDL code as a block also DAC as another block. If there is an error in the digital interface code, I can understand it from the output with measuring. You might want to think about what I'm saying in Tina/Multisim similar softwares.

Comment: I would just write a I2C/SPI agent/BFM (behavioral model).  No need for the ADC